# Why defining seperable topological space we use "COUNTABLE" dense set?

Tags: general-topology, definition, separable-spaces

My question is the caption itself. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Don't understand. The definition is exactly that. A separable space is one that contains an at most countable dense subset. What do you mean why? Perhaps, such a feature has been observed about some spaces and dubbed "separability".

Comment: It's a historic name, admittedly, not very good since it has nothing to do with "separation axioms" in topology. The countability assumption is closely related to other things like sequential convergence (and 1st countability), 2nd countability property. In principle, there is nothing wrong considering a similar property for dense subsets of higher cardinality, just not very useful in applications of general topology to other areas of math. (For instance, not too many people care about topological spaces of cardinality higher than continuum.)

Comment: @MoisheCohen: I would argue that not many people care about topological space at all, if that's the attitude one is taking. (One should never be too cavalier in mathematics when saying things like "not many people care about this or that", since there is always the risk of being myopic and seeing only what is in your research field and its close-by neighbors.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Dear Asaf, I respectfully disagree. Indeed, not many people care about modern research in topology (say, validity of the Novikov conjecture, for example). However, if you choose any field of math in the AMS subject classification in the interval  from 11 (number theory)  through 59 (this covers most of pure math, sorry, I skipped your area), as well as some areas outside that range, e.g. 05, 74, 76, 81, 83, 85, I will explain why people in that area care about the topology at least in its most basic (general topology) form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a clever definition where the key appears to be taking a *small* number of points as being dense. For one thing a larger number of points has an easier time being dense...  I guess one might try replacing countable with finite,  and look at a smaller class of spaces.  But to make things more interesting,  countable was used in the definition.  Of course countable is the smallest level of infinity.   A countable set can be put in a list.  In the case of a separable topological space, I guess you could almost think of the points being partitioned, if you will, or *separated* by the subset.

If you went in the other direction and said, instead of countable,  $\aleph_3 $, or $\aleph_{1000}$, or higher cardinality yet, you would have something a little more obscure and hard to get a feel for...  though still interesting perhaps. ..

Of course,  it's a *definition*...  When you define something,  you can be creative and define *whatever you want*, quite apart from whether such things even exist,  or proving theorems about them...

Answer (score 2):

It is convenient to be able to name each point in a space. If the space is countable, then there is no difficulty in doing so. If the space is uncountable, then attaching a name to each point is impossible. However, if a countable dense set is present, then you can name each point in the space by a sequence from that countable set. This gives you a rather simple mechanism to be able to 'reach' every point in the space.

In more technical terms, having a countable dense set allows for recursive constructions and inductive proofs in the space without the need for any transfinite arguments past $\omega$.

Answer (score 1):

First reason: it is a useful definition. If a space $X$ is separable and we want to prove some properties of it, we can first work on the countable subset $C$ which is much easier to handle. Afterwards we can take the closure of $C$, i.e. limits.

Second reason, omitting the condition "countable" makes the definition useless, because every space is dense in itself.